# Using SideBar Navigation component with iOS.Xamarin Storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigation-drawer, sidebar

I am using the [Sidebar Navigation component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sidebarnavigation) for my Xamarin.iOS project. I am using Storyboards to create my ViewControllers for the Menu and Content.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
var content = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("ContentControllerId") as ContentViewController;
var menu = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("MenuControllerId") as SideMenuController;

sideBar = new SidebarController (this, content, menu);
```

In the content I have a view controller with a `UITableview`. So when I click the menu item I want to do some action on the content's table view and reload the data.

I do this by calling `contentViewController.CreateTable();`, where `CreateTable()` does some operations and reloads the table data. But right now when I do this, the tableView and other components in the content view controller are `null`.

Any idea how I can solve this?